# Run a project from github locally (no implementation / compile option)

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-support-library

I want to import and run this specific library locally for testing purposes [Credntia/CVScanner](https://github.com/Credntia/CVScanner), this library didn't suggest any implementation (compile) method to use it. I try to import it as a module, but none of my tests have worked for me.. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a closer look, you'll notice the author is using bintray and the android-gradle-maven plugin. Therefore, you can clone the repo, install the artifact into your local maven instance ('mavenLocal()' from gradle), or import it from bintray. You'll need the bintray repo for that. You can get it at https://bintray.com/iammehedi/Maven/online.devliving:cvscanner (just check the wrench icon, 'set me up'). Also, the artifact is importing the OpenCVAndroid artifact, so you'll need the bintray repo for that too. Get it here: https://github.com/steveliles/opencv-android

Comment: thx your comment helps me a lot to resolve my problem that's why I mention it as a correct answer